# Wrong Panel Icon images

Tags: lubuntu, icons, panel, lxqt

I've never had this issue with previous distros of Lubuntu. I've reinstalled it now and still icons seem to disappear. First it was the battery showing a setting symbol, now the wifi shows a settings symbol. Any help would be great. This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Solving this myself. It appears that when you over-ride icon theme issues occur.

Comment: Your release of Lubuntu maybe a start.  Yes we could guess, but exact detail allows for better answers

Comment: Which details do you want? It appears that the themes are conflicting with one another somehow.

Comment: If you want specific help, ask a specific question. What version of Lubuntu are you using? Exactly what themes are causing the problems? Otherwise people are just guessing.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry Organic. I'm running 19.04. And basically what is happening is that the themes are not quite working properly. I'm trying to use the GNOME default theme for my icons. And I'm trying to use a different theme for the panel, but as I've said it seems that icons disappear. Either the wifi, battery, or flux. Sometimes when I unplug the battery the icon changes to the setting icon. And other times when I boot flux is the setting icon. So I'm really not sure what is happening.

Comment: Sometimes, stopping the panel and starting it again fixes the icons. Or if I change themes it sometimes fixes the icons. But things are not stable.